# Call a server side button click function from client side

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a button like this:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="btnDeleteActivity" OnClientClick="return ConfirmDelete()" OnClick="btnDeleteActivity_Click">
     Delete activity
</asp:LinkButton>
```

and this HTML:

```
<i class="fa fa-trash" onclick="DeleteActivity()"></i>
```

in JS I have this:

```
function DeleteActivity() {
   document.getElementById('<%= btnDeleteActivity.ClientID %>').click();
}
```

The problem is that when I click on the i element, **it calls only the OnClientClick** of the button, **and ignores the OnClick**. (the JS function inside OnClientClick is just a simple return confirm('some message'))

I tried to delete the OnClientClick and test only with the OnClick on the button, but it still not calling it. When I test clicking directly on the button, it works perfectly.

Someone have an idea of what can be the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either alter JavaScript function `ConfirmDelete()` to return `true` when clicked by the `i` tag (by setting a global variable).

Or add **another** button which doesn't display or contain a JavaScript OnClick to handle the post back.

**For example:**

```
<asp:LinkButton
    style="display:none;"
    runat="server"
    ID="btnHiddenDeleteActivity" 
    OnClick="btnDeleteActivity_Click">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Alternatively you can just call PostBack

```
function DeleteActivity() {
   __doPostBack('<%= btnDeleteActivity.UniqueID %>','')
}
```

Comment: I used __doPostBack and it worked! Thanks man!